# using System;MVC Storefront- Rob Conery reference tricky?

Tags: model-view-controller

I follow the StoreFront MVC Application video tuturial made by rob conery.
I noticed that the Commerce.MVC.Web reference both the Commerce.MVC.Data and Commerce.MVC.Services. This is because the Commerce.MVC.Web needs the Commerce.MVC.Data because of the entities defined with in it.
What is the better way to reference the Commerce.MVC.Services only. Do I need to put the Entities in the service?or any suggestions?

The bold text is came from Commerce.MVC.Data:

```
Commerce.MVC.Data
Commerce.MVC.Services- reference the Commerce.MVC.Data
Commerce.MVC.Web - reference both the Commerce.MVC.Data and Commerce.MVC.Services
```

Here the sample code from CatalogController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Commerce.MVC.Data;
using Commerce.MVC.Services;

namespace Commerce.MVC.Web.Controllers {
    public class CatalogController : Controller {

        #region .ctor
        ICatalogService _catalogService;

        public CatalogController(ICatalogService catalogService) {
            _catalogService = catalogService;
        }

        #endregion  

        #region ViewData
        /// <summary>
        /// Class used for transferring data to the View
        /// </summary>
        public class CatalogData {

            public CatalogData() { }
            public CatalogData(List<Category> categories, Category parent, Category child) {
                this.Categories = categories;
                this.Category = parent;
                this.SubCategory = child;
            }

            public IList<Category> Categories;

           //The below is came from Commerce.NVC.Data

            public Product Product { get; set; }
            public Category Category { get; set; }
            public Category SubCategory { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it matters massively (no pun intended) but we generally separate out the entities into a Model assembly which is shared across all layers.

So our structure is:

Company.Project.Model
Company.Project.Infrastructure

Company.Project.Web
Company.Project.Services
Company.Project.Data

The Model and Infrastructure (cross cutting concerns) are referenced across all layers with Web/Services/Data only able to talk to the layer immediately below.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @JoeR Yes we do.  Nothing I said would preclude using DI.  Web will call into Services via interfaces resolved through DI.  Likewise Services will resolve Data interfaces through DI.  If Web tries to take a dependency on interfaces exposed within the Data Namespace that would break the Architectural design.  The architecture tooling in VS2010 allows us to model this restriction and break the build upon violation.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Using Visual Studio to help maintain the intended design. Thanks for the clarification, I think if user335160 was really worried about coders directly using data access in the web, your solution would be a good one.

Comment: @Daz Lewiz- if you don't mind, will you please post some codes for others also to have an idea?

Answer (score 9):

Edited Response...

You can use the Service just fine, but the service returns *something* and that *something* is your Entities. In order for your Web app to use those Entities it needs to reference the class containing the Entities right?

Now you can get around this by returning Anonymous types, or maybe creating your own DTOs - but then you lose validations and everything the Entity has declared on it. In effect - you're duplicating your code.

Do you see this?

Comment: yes, I only need to reference the Services in the Controller minus the Commerce.MV.Data. I dont want to expose the Commerce.MVC.Data, because if I do that, some of my methods and functions are also accesible. Yes, the site needs the Entities which belong to Commerce.MVC.Data, is this really a good approach to access the Commerce.MVC.Data from the Controller?

Comment: So are you worried that code from the website will call your data access code directly, rather than via the service?

Answer (score 0):

I think the architecture in Rob's app is fine.

If you are worried that code from the website will call your data access code directly, rather than via the service, this is a legitimate concern.

However, if your website is setup with a dependency injection framework, you will not see data access classes being instantiated.

This should reduce the chances of someone new to your project instantiating data access classes directly, which obviously would be very bad...

This is why projects should always have code reviews. :)

Answer (score 0):

I emailed this same question to Rob about a year ago and his response made me realise I was confusing the physical separation of code with the logical separation using namespaces.

If you still dont want to reference the entities from two different namespaces then you can use view models to dis-intermediate (and use a tool like automapper) however this is much more code.